# Questions about edge detection in an image

Tags: image-processing

I think for those images with many edges, it would be more useful to use color images because this will give greater image gradient, so shaper edeges is detected. However, I have no ideas about the second questions. Does it mean we can add linear transformations or some constant value to the image?

[image]

Comment: You could calculate edges using sobel operator for `R`, `G`, and `B` components, and take the mean value of the three calculated edge maps.

Comment: The second question is rather stupid. I could write 10 pages to answer it. How is anyone supposed to know how much of an answer is expected for those points?
And how should you give a meaningful answer without knowing how the real image looks like. Maybe half of those trees are brown?
And what in gods name is a basic operation supposed to be?
There are houndreds of things you could do to those images to improve edge detection.